# Pull Information using JSOUP fro HTML having duplicate class name?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to implement the webcrawler using java and JSOUP. I have following Html Contents

```
<div class="backgroundSection">
        <span class="lndustryProductLinks">
  <span class="backgroundDetailHeading">Industry:&nbsp;</span><a class="criterion" rel="nofollow" href="#industryList=[{value:'66826',isUsed:true}]&amp;level=0&amp;type=company">Automotive Service &amp; Collision Repair</a>
                        ,
<a class="criterion" rel="nofollow" href="#industryList=[{value:'1290',isUsed:true}]&amp;level=0&amp;type=company">Consumer Services</a>
            </span>
        </div>

<div class="backgroundSection">
<span class="backgroundDetailHeading">Products and Services:&nbsp;</span>
`<span class="lndustryProductLinks"><a class="criterion"`href="#industryKeywords='windshield auto glass replacement services'&amp;level=0&amp;type=company" rel="NOFOLLOW">windshield auto glass replacement services</a>`
<a class="criterion" href="#industryKeywords='free mobile windshield repair services'&amp;level=0&amp;type=company" rel="NOFOLLOW">free mobile windshield repair services</a>
,


<a class="criterion" href="#industryKeywords='local automotive glass services'&amp;level=0&amp;type=company" rel="NOFOLLOW">local automotive glass services</a></span></div>
```

When I try to get the Industry links (Consumer Services) using below code :

```
public String getIndustry(String url)
    {
        String text=null;
        String nilav=null;
        try
        {
            doc=Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements e=doc.getElementsByClass("backgroundDetailHeading");
            text=e.text();

        }

        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return text;            
    }
```

I get the links of div class Products and Services also. But I want criterion class value of Industry div class only. How could I do it?

Comment: This is hard to answer without additional info. For example, is the div you want always the first one? Or is it always named "Industry"? Depending on that you need to construct the selectors. Look into CSS selectors in JSoup.